# How can I shorten this expression? $\frac {-x \cdot a_1 -x\cdot a_2 -x\cdot a_3 -u}{a_4}\cdot l$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have this fraction:
$$\frac {-x \cdot a_1 -x\cdot a_2 -x\cdot a_3 -u}{a_4} \cdot l$$

You see, there are many $-x$ terms. How can I make this shorter? Can I write:

$$x\,\frac { -a_1 -a_2 -a_3}{a_4} \cdot l  -u\,\frac { l}{a_4}$$

Is this right?

Regards.

Comment: I've tested that the first freaction (without -u) is right, but the second seems to be wrong. I neet the X's down

Comment: I don't see a particular reason to separate the $x$-stuff and $u$-stuff, although it isn't wrong to do so. I'd probably choose to rewrite the expression as $$-\frac{l}{a_4}\left(\,x(a_1+a_2+a_3)+u\;\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do $$\frac{-a_1x-a_2x-a_3x -u}{a_4}l = \left(\frac{-a_1x-a_2x-a_3x}{a_4}-\frac{u}{a_4}\right)l = -x l \frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3}{a_4} - l \frac{u}{a_4}$$ but there is nothing shorter.

Comment: Thank you, that looks easy to understand for me. And also its exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: This does not play any role. You can also write $$-\frac{lu}{a_4}$$ It is the same (surely if you are workin on a field, which I suppose).

Comment: Okay, what if i want get completely get rid of the -u in the numerator? Is this possible?

Comment: @raviolican No, that is not possible.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean. You cannot get rid of $u$ Perhaps you want to write $$-u\frac{l}{a_4}$$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek ahh is $$- l \frac{u}{a_4}$$ the same as $$-u\,\frac { l}{a_4}$$ right? seems so..